# Install Jetty or run embedded for Solr install

Tags: solr, jetty

I am about to install Solr on a production box. It will be the only Java applet running and be on the same box as the web server (nginx).

It seems there are two options.

1. Install Jetty separately and configure to use with Solr
2. Set Solr's embedded Jetty server to start as a service and just use that

Is there any performance benefit in having them separate?

I am a big fan of KISS, the less setup the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want KISS there is no question: 2. stick to vanilla Solr distrib with included jetty.

Doing the work of installing an external servlet engine would make sense if you needed Tomcat for example, but just to use the same thing (Jetty) Solr already includes...no way.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is still using jetty 6. So there would be some benefits if you can get the solr application to run in a recent jetty distribution. For example you could use jetty 9 and use features like SPDY to enhance the response times of your application.

However I have no idea or experience if it's possible to run the solr application standalone in a servlet engine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for running Solr and keeping it simple is to use Solr-Undertow which is a high performance with small footprint server for Solr. It is easy to use on local machines for development and also production. It supports simple config files for running instances with different data directories, ports and more.  It also can run just by pointing it at a distribution .zip file without needing to unpack it.

(note, I am the author of Solr-Undertow)

Link here: https://github.com/bremeld/solr-undertow with releases under the "Releases" tab.